# How to convert JSON to a dataframe with python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

How do I open a json file and turn it into a dataframe? I want to create graphs with Plotly later but I cannot seem to create a dataframe.

```
def open_file(filename):
  with open(filename, "r") as file:
    file_list = json.load(file)
    output_df = pd.DataFrame(file_list)
    return output_df


open_file("LT.json")
```

The error I get:

> ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")

Comment: Use [`pandas.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_json.html).

Comment: share the json and explain how the df should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")` is telling you that you passed the incorrect type of data to the DataFrame. So, most probably file_list is not a dictionary.
In my case, your code is 100% working. So, I think the problem is definitely from the JSON file. Maybe file_list is a type of string. If that is the case, using the eval method might help.

```
output_df = pd.DataFrame(eval(file_list))
```

But using `pandas.read_json` works 99% of the time

```
output_df = pd.read_json(filename)
```